# Quickest way to find if abs(z) <= C for complex numbers in python

Tags: python, performance, math, complex-numbers

I need to find the best (quickest) way to check for a given complex number z if its absolute value is smaller or equal to some arbitrary static number, E.G 6.

#### My tries

The naive approach I used is:

```
def check(z):
    if abs(z) <= 6:
        return True
    return False
```

But since calculating the absolute value of a complex number in cartesian representation (which *I assume* is the way in which python stores complex numbers) requires calculating a square root, I thought that squaring both sides would be quicker E.G

```
def check2(z):
    if z.real**2 + z.imag**2 <= 36:
        return True
    return False
```

Or some other method of squaring, like

```
def check3(z):
   if z.real*z.real + z.imag*z.imag <= 36:
       return True
   return False
```

But while testing, I found that the first method is quicker by a large margin.

Is the first method really the quickest? If so, how? I found no documentation on how python handles complex number methods internally.

Comment: My guess is that the first way runs C code, which is usually faster than python.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Doc/c-api/complex.rst

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/complexobject.c

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Python/pymath.c#L35

Comment: You could squeeze out more performance if you just changed your function to `def check(z): return abs(z) <= 6`.  Fewer instructions/branching == faster execution.

Comment: Other considerations are going to swamp any theoretical consideration at this level. CPython built-in functions push most calculations down into the C-level. Just a simple Python-level expression like `z.real**2` requires an attribute resolution (probably way more expensive than anything else) and an extra `**` operation, which is an *additional* method resolution.

Comment: Summary of @wwii's links: `abs` of `complex` devolves to a C level call to `hypot(c.real, c.imag)` (assuming the real and imaginary components are finite). The real savings for `abs` is in the fact that all the attribute lookups, squaring, and square root calculations are done in a single Python level function call (relatively expensive, but paid once) that performs all the (really cheap) calculations in C without further Python overhead, vs. paying Python overhead for each of the cheap steps (the overhead vastly outweighing the actual work done).

Answer (score 2):

The *builtin* functions are written in *C*, that is why they are faster. You can `import dis from dis` to see that `check` has only 10 instructions while the other methods have 13.

And even then I want to point out that you are cheating! You are doing some computations for the function. The general case would be this.

```
def check(z, n):
    if abs(z) <= n:
        return True
    return False

def check2(z, n):
    if z.real ** 2 + z.imag ** 2 <= n ** 2:
        return True
    return False
```

So you do save a square root in`check2`, but that is at the price of squaring.

Comment: How many instructions would there be if they changed it to `def check(z, n): return abs(z) <= n`?

Comment: It's even better with 5. Although, since there is an if-else fork, the  longest sequence of instruction the original function could have executed was 8, so we only save 3 instructions. One which is `POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE` and one that is `LOAD_CONST (TRUE)`, and those are really not much compared to the rest.

Comment: We're not in the realm where time complexities matter. All these operations are O(1) on fixed-precision floats (fixed-precision, not fixed-point). It's just a matter of constant factors.

Comment: Also, 6 is fixed, so hardcoding 36 isn't cheating. We are specifically *not* writing a function for a general upper bound.

Comment: Every time complexity involved here is O(1). Your link goes to time complexities for arbitrary-precision arithmetic algorithms, not floating-point math.